# Qt: the correct way to display a large amount of real time data as text?

Tags: c++, qt

If I have a large amount of real time data, say 100 gps locations every 0.5 second. And I would like to display them on the same screen as text. What is the best solutions out there?
Currently I used 100 QLabels, and it cause the GUI thread to jam.
Will a tableview with a QStandardItemModel give faster response?

If I use tableview, shall I use 1 table view to display all 100 gps locations or 100 tableviews?

Comment: Why bother to display 200 lines of text a second? No one can read it!  If you are displaying GPS coordinates, surely dots on a map would be more useful for at-a-glance display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating every 0.5 seconds a lot of labels can be expensive, from machine to machine. You may write your own [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) subclass which re-implements the [paintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) to display the content of a QStringList of 100 elements. **You may have the QWidget schedule an update every 1 or 2 seconds and in the meantime change the underlying [QStringList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) model from where the paintEvent takes the data to display.**

You are going to use a [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) which is pretty straightforward in letting you draw text on a widget. You'll end up using [QPainter::drawText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText) or one of its reimpmlementations.

**NOTE** that if the QStringList is updated from a different thread you may want to use a QMutex in order to handle accesses to the data. Otherwise you may schedule screen updates and data updates on the same thread, the GUI one.

Comment: So I should use one QWidget and reimplement its paintevent instead of using 100 QWidget right?

Comment: That would surely be more efficient in terms of memory and paint events triggered.